# Swift - Find number that is a multiple of all numbers 1...20

Tags: swift, loops, modulo

I am working on [Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problem 5 which is:

*2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?*

I am having trouble with my nested loops. I have a `for` loop within in a `while` loop. My logic is I
check a number (`currentNumber`)  against 1-20 (`i`), if `currentNumber` is not a multiple of `i` (checked using modular arithmatic)
then it breaks out of that loop and trys the next largest number.

My issue is I cannot figure out how to jump out of **only** my inner loop and not my outer loop. Here is my code:

```
class Five {
    init() {
        var currentNumber = 1

        while true {
            for i in 1...20 {
                if currentNumber % i != 0 {
                    currentNumber += 1
                    continue
                }
            }

            break
        }

        print("the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible " +
            "by all of the numbers from 1 to 20 is \(currentNumber)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got a good and correct answer. Just as an add-on, for the
sake of completeness:

An alternative to labeled continue statements is to move the inner loop into a separate function from which you can “early return”:

```
func isDivisibleBy1To20(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    for j in 2...20 {
        if number % j != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

var currentNumber = 1
while !isDivisibleBy1To20(currentNumber) {
    currentNumber += 1
}

print("solution:", currentNumber)
```

Using functional methods this can be simplified to

```
func isDivisibleBy1To20(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    return !(2...20).contains(where: { number % $0 != 0 })
}

let solution = (1...).first(where: isDivisibleBy1To20)!

print("solution:", solution)
```

(*Remark:* There are other, much faster methods to solve this problem.)

Comment: What are the faster methods?

Comment: @keepIT100 I don’t want to spoil the fun of finding that out yourself! Just as a hint, it is related to some (simple) number theoretic functions. If you really don’t want to solve it yourself, just search for "Euler 5" on codereview.stackexchange.com .